# A counterexample 2

Tags: calculus, integration, examples-counterexamples

Can we find a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to(0,\infty)$  which satisfies

$$\limsup_{|x|\to + \infty}\frac{f(x+c)}{f(x)}<+\infty, \ \ \forall c\in \mathbb{R},(\text{limit in }+\infty\text{ and }-\infty),\tag{1}\label{1}$$

$$\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}}\int_t^{t+1}f(x)dx<+\infty,\tag{2}\label{2}$$
and 
$$\limsup_{r\to + \infty}\frac{r}{\int_{-r}^r f(x)dx}<+\infty,\tag{3}\label{3}$$
**but not**
$$\limsup\limits _{r\to\infty}\frac{r^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\int_{-r}^{r}f^{q}\left(x\right)dx\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}}{\int_{-r}^{r}f\left(x\right)dx}<+\infty,\tag{4}\label{4}$$
where $q>1.$

**Note:** I see that $f$ must not be bounded because in this case $\eqref{3}$ will automatically imply $\eqref{4}$. $f$ also should  not touch $0$ because of $\eqref{1}$.

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798381/a-counterexample) question.

Comment: Is this the most descriptive title you could come up with?

Comment: I suspect that the combination of (1) and (2) implies that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: @900sit-upsaday  Sorry, I did not know what to put in the title :). I also feel that $f$ bounded can result from these conditions. I think I should investigate what kind of conditions we can add to (2) to make $f$ bounded. Thank you for your comment !!!